# Ember context missunderstanding

Tags: javascript, ember.js, youtube

Ive been at it for the whole day, and there is obviously something basic im missing here, please help me understand what it is.

Im trying to create a youtube playlist application, as first step Im trying to search youtube for relevant videos and return the result to my model for this route.

The only thing I know for sure is that the search function is working fine, because I took if from another project. There is something wrong with the way I put the values into model..

Here is what I got so far:

## app.js

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('SearchYT');
    this.resource('Play');
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect : function() {
        this.transitionTo('SearchYT');
    }
});

App.SearchYTRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function() {
        return App.Video.all();
    }
});

App.Video = Ember.Object.extend({
    title : null,
    seconds : null,
    yid : null
});

App.Video.reopenClass({
    // there are no videos initially
    content : [],

    // Searching flag
    isSearching : false,

    actions : {
        makeSearch : function() {
            console.log('working1');

            // Start searching and remove existing results
            this.set('isSearching', true);
            this.set('content', []);

            var query = this.get('searchString');
            var c = $.getJSON("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos", {
                alt : 'json',
                'max-results' : 10,
                v : 2,
                q : query
            });
            c.success(function(data) {
                var entries = data.feed.entry, results = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
                    var e = entries[i];
                    results.push(App.Video.create({
                        yid : e.id.$t.split(':')[3],
                        seconds : parseInt(e.media$group.yt$duration.seconds),
                        title : e.title.$t
                    }));
                }
                this.set('content', results);
            });

            c.complete(function() {
                this.set('isSearching', false);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Please help me understand my problem,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an Ember issue, you're out of scope when you try and set the content.  I've updated your code a bit showing two ways to handle this, one keeping a reference to this, and the second keeping a reference to an array.

```
    makeSearch : function() {
        console.log('working1');

        // Start searching and remove existing results
        // keep a reference to the new array, then use `pushObject`
        var newResults = [],
            self = this;
        this.set('isSearching', true);
        this.set('content', newResults);

        var query = this.get('searchString');
        var c = $.getJSON("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos", {
            alt : 'json',
            'max-results' : 10,
            v : 2,
            q : query
        });
        c.success(function(data) {
            var entries = data.feed.entry, results = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
                var e = entries[i];
                newResults.pushObject(App.Video.create({
                    yid : e.id.$t.split(':')[3],
                    seconds : parseInt(e.media$group.yt$duration.seconds),
                    title : e.title.$t
                }));
            }
            //  this.set('content', results); <-- this here is not the this out of the success
        });

        c.complete(function() {
            self.set('isSearching', false); // <-- same here, this is different
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you're reply! it still dosent work though.. now it's telling me the following:
while processing route: SearchYT undefined is not a function TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: `all` isn't defined on `App.Video`.  You are calling `App.Video.all()`, but you've never defined `all` on it.